# Using the compatibility APIs

Tags: java, android, osx-lion

I am trying to use the compability APIs (android.support.v4.app)
I have downloaded them and am now trying to use them in my project as described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html, i.e. copying the libraries to my project 'libs' folder then right clicking on the files and 'add to build path'.
However, eclipse seems oblivious to this, it does not recognise, in my example 'FragmentActivity' whereas it is defined in the FragmentActivity.jar I have just added to my build path, furthermore, in the statement 'import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;', android.support is still underlined in red.
I have tried cleaning my project, restarting eclipse and my mac many times to no avail.
I am using MAC OSX Lion + indigo+r20
Oh! and adding the libraries one by one to my code tree is neither neat nor practical as it leads to conflicts.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the library then you just have to make sure you're importing the correct things.

If I want to use the compatability library these are the steps I take:

**1.** Create new project

**2.** Right click on the project > Android Tools > Add Support Library

**3.** Add these two lines of code

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();`

**4.** Add correct imports by hovering over the red lines and selecting the v4 library.

Though, I'm pretty sure the newest version of SDK and ADT adds the support library by standard which cuts out step number **2**.

*Note:* You don't have to right click the project > properties > Android > and add the support library. That's only for other libraries like ActionBarSherlock or anything else you find.

Comment: Many thanks. I did step 2 from my existing project, which solved my problem.